# Ansible - merge two dictionary lists

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to figure out how to combine two dicts of varying sizes.  The intent is to add additional recipients to the recipients list in a third dictionary.

```
mail_aliases_list:
  - name: mailer-daemon
    recipients:
      - foo
  - name: postmaster
    recipients:
      - bar
  - name: bin
    recipients:
      - baz
  ...
```

and

```
mail_aliases_defaults:
  - name: mailer-daemon
    recipients:
      - postmaster
  - name: postmaster
    recipients:
      - root
  - name: bin
    recipients:
      - root
  ...
```

Resulting in

```
mail_aliases:
  - name: mailer-daemon
    recipients:
      - postmaster
      - foo
  - name: postmaster
    recipients:
      - root
      - bar
  - name: bin
    recipients:
      - root
      - baz
  ...
```

This is a bit beyond my understanding of filters and I'm frustrated that I even have to ask for help but hopefully I'll learn something in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to do exactly what you want, and the way your data is structured makes it a little more difficult.  If you turn `mail_aliases_list` and `mail_aliases_defaults` into dictionaries, it becomes easier to achieve your desired end state.

Something like:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  vars:
    mail_aliases_overrides:
      mailer-daemon:
        recipients:
          - foo
      postmaster:
        recipients:
          - bar
      bin:
        recipients:
          - baz
      not_in_defaults:
        recipients:
          - bob
    mail_aliases_defaults:
      mailer-daemon:
        recipients:
          - postmaster
      postmaster:
        recipients:
          - root
      bin:
        recipients:
          - root
      only_in_defaults:
        recipients:
          - alice

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        mail_aliases: >-
          {{ mail_aliases|default({})|combine({item:
          (mail_aliases_overrides[item]|default({'recipients': []})).recipients +
          (mail_aliases_defaults[item]|default({'recipients': []})).recipients
          })
          }}
      loop: "{{ (mail_aliases_overrides.keys()|list + mail_aliases_defaults.keys()|list)|unique }}"

    - debug:
        var: mail_aliases
```

This will generate as output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=mailer-daemon)
ok: [localhost] => (item=postmaster)
ok: [localhost] => (item=bin)
ok: [localhost] => (item=not_in_defaults)
ok: [localhost] => (item=only_in_defaults)

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mail_aliases": {
        "bin": [
            "baz",
            "root"
        ],
        "mailer-daemon": [
            "foo",
            "postmaster"
        ],
        "not_in_defaults": [
            "bob"
        ],
        "only_in_defaults": [
            "alice"
        ],
        "postmaster": [
            "bar",
            "root"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I've made sure this works with keys that only exist in one of `mail_aliases_defaults` or `mail_aliases_overrides`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this and report back.  This looks very promising and may actually be a useful pattern I can use for some other roles.  I've read that it's difficult to merge dictionaries in ansible so I've been avoiding them but I think this might be the solution I've been looking for.

Comment: This is going to be used in a jinja2 template to write the mail aliases so it's going to have to be iterable.  I thought the way to do that would be to just set a fact with mail_aliases_overrides.keys() + mail_aliases_defaults.keys(), but that isn't going to work since + is an unsupported operand for dict_keys.  I'm thinking combine the two dictionaries and then change the template to use the keys from the resulting merged dictionary.

Comment: Update: I've updated the playbook so it will work with python3 as well.  Give it a shot. I've also added a `|unique` filter which was missing in the first draft, so that you don't end up with duplicate results.

Comment: This looks good.  Can you set the resulting dictionary as a fact and then debug the fact var, instead of debugging it directly, I'm having trouble seeing how to make this into a var.

Comment: See my update, which now builds a new variable from the source data.

Comment: Something is not quite right.  The output should be much longer, at least for me.  I have like ~70 keys in mail_aliases_defaults.  I was expecting to see all of them but with four of them having additional recipients from mail_aliases_overrides. However, I'm only seeing merging for the ones that have recipients in mail_alias_overrides.  Does that make sense? Also, I can't believe I didn't notice at first but the keys are there but not the recipients. I'll attach a pastebin or something to show you. I can't do it in this comment field.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hKyJ58dm - Fixed an indent problem.  This is the results I'm getting now.  This looks much better.  I'm going to try to use this in the jinja template.

Comment: Thank you, works great. You absolutely deserve even more than a correct answer.